# Facebook Friends List Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

I am trying to run a function to see Facebook friends so users can see which are currently using the app. I have done some researching and found some older code but nothing that works with Swift 3. Here is what I have right now:

```
var fbRequestFriends: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.requestForMyFriends()

    fbRequestFriends.startWithCompletionHandler{
        (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!,result:AnyObject?, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil && result != nil {
            print("Request Friends result : \(result!)")
        } else {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
    }
```

It will not run because FBSDKGraphRequest does not have a requestForMyFriends. Does anyone know how to update this in order to work on swift 3?

I have also found this on Facebook Docs but it is all in Obj C but am having issues converting it:

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{friend-list-id}"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

Comment: Facebook updated their policies for getting the friend list and for other apis. Have a look at policy changes.

Comment: I did, the code I have above in Obj C seems to work for other users who have authorized the app, I just do not know how to convert it to swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that you looking for is:

```
var fbRequestFriends: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/{friend-list-id}", parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]())

fbRequestFriends.start { (connection, result, error) in
    if error == nil && result != nil {
        print("Request Friends result : \(result!)")
    } else {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }
}
```

It will execute the request, I do not guarantee that it will work for various reasons, for example - you need permission to ask for a friends list.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. Could you help me so that for each friend it prints their id? I am having problems because the structure is "friends": {
    data =     (
                {
            id = 10104336248623278;
            name = "John Smith";
        },

Comment: @user3255746 use tutorial to lear how to parse json in ios. And mark that question as complete.